# How do I add clock function to led timer

Tags: javascript, html, svg, timer, clock

So far for my project I have to create an led clock where I can view the current time, set a timer, and change the color of the led. So far I have the clock drawn out with SVG, however I cannot figure out how to get it to actually display the time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Project</title>
        <script>
          /*function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
          }
          function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
            return i;
          }*/
          var svgUnderlay = d3.select("svg"),
            svgOverlay = d3.select("body").append(function() { return svgUnderlay.node().cloneNode(true); }),
            svg = d3.selectAll("svg");
            svgUnderlay.attr("id", "underlay");
            svgOverlay.attr("id", "overlay");
          var digit = svg.selectAll(".digit"),
            separator = svg.selectAll(".separator circle");
          var digitPattern = [
            [1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1],
            [0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1],
            [1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],
            [1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]
          ];
          (function tick() {
            var now = new Date,
              hours = now.getHours(),
              minutes = now.getMinutes(),
              seconds = now.getSeconds();
              digit = digit.data([hours / 10 | 0, hours % 10, minutes / 10 | 0, minutes % 10, seconds / 10 | 0, seconds % 10]);
              digit.select("path:nth-child(1)").classed("lit", function(d) { return digitPattern[0][d]; });
              digit.select("path:nth-child(2)").classed("lit", function(d) { return digitPattern[1][d]; });
              digit.select("path:nth-child(3)").classed("lit", function(d) { return digitPattern[2][d]; });
              digit.select("path:nth-child(4)").classed("lit", function(d) { return digitPattern[3][d]; });
              digit.select("path:nth-child(5)").classed("lit", function(d) { return digitPattern[4][d]; });
              digit.select("path:nth-child(6)").classed("lit", function(d) { return digitPattern[5][d]; });
              digit.select("path:nth-child(7)").classed("lit", function(d) { return digitPattern[6][d]; });
              separator.classed("lit", seconds & 1);
              setTimeout(tick, 1000 - now % 1000);
          })();
        </script>
        <style>
            body {
              background: #111;
            }
            svg {
              position: absolute;
              /* top: 0; */
              /* left: 50px; */
              width: 364px;
              height: 312px;
            }
            #underlay path, #underlay circle {
              fill: none;
            }
            #underlay .lit {
              fill: #0e0;
              stroke: #0e0;
            }
            #overlay path, #overlay circle {
              fill: #222;
              stroke: #0e0;
              stroke-opacity: 0;
            }
            #overlay .lit {
              fill: #0e0;
              stroke-opacity: 1;
            }
            h1 {
              color: white;
            }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body onload="startTime()">
        <h1>Clock</h1>
        <svg id="clock" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 375 96">
          <g transform="translate(17,0)">
            <g class="digit" transform="skewX(-12)">
                <path d="M10,8L14,4L42,4L46,8L42,12L14,12L10,8z"/>
                <path d="M8,10L12,14L12,42L8,46L4,42L4,14L8,10z"/>
                <path d="M48,10L52,14L52,42L48,46L44,42L44,14L48,10z"/>
                <path d="M10,48L14,44L42,44L46,48L42,52L14,52L10,48z"/>
                <path d="M8,50L12,54L12,82L8,86L4,82L4,54L8,50z"/>
                <path d="M48,50L52,54L52,82L48,86L44,82L44,54L48,50z"/>
                <path d="M10,88L14,84L42,84L46,88L42,92L14,92L10,88z"/>
            </g>
            <g class="digit" transform="skewX(-12)">
                <path d="M66,8L70,4L98,4L102,8L98,12L70,12L66,8z"/>
                <path d="M64,10L68,14L68,42L64,46L60,42L60,14L64,10z"/>
                <path d="M104,10L108,14L108,42L104,46L100,42L100,14L104,10z"/>
                <path d="M66,48L70,44L98,44L102,48L98,52L70,52L66,48z"/>
                <path d="M64,50L68,54L68,82L64,86L60,82L60,54L64,50z"/>
                <path d="M104,50L108,54L108,82L104,86L100,82L100,54L104,50z"/>
                <path d="M66,88L70,84L98,84L102,88L98,92L70,92L66,88z"/>
            </g>
            <g class="separator">
                <circle r="4" cx="112" cy="28"/>
                <circle r="4" cx="103.5" cy="68"/>
            </g>
            <g class="digit" transform="skewX(-12)">
                <path d="M134,8L138,4L166,4L170,8L166,12L138,12L134,8z"/>
                <path d="M132,10L136,14L136,42L132,46L128,42L128,14L132,10z"/>
                <path d="M172,10L176,14L176,42L172,46L168,42L168,14L172,10z"/>
                <path d="M134,48L138,44L166,44L170,48L166,52L138,52L134,48z"/>
                <path d="M132,50L136,54L136,82L132,86L128,82L128,54L132,50z"/>
                <path d="M172,50L176,54L176,82L172,86L168,82L168,54L172,50z"/>
                <path d="M134,88L138,84L166,84L170,88L166,92L138,92L134,88z"/>
            </g>
            <g class="digit" transform="skewX(-12)">
                <path d="M190,8L194,4L222,4L226,8L222,12L194,12L190,8z"/>
                <path d="M188,10L192,14L192,42L188,46L184,42L184,14L188,10z"/>
                <path d="M228,10L232,14L232,42L228,46L224,42L224,14L228,10z"/>
                <path d="M190,48L194,44L222,44L226,48L222,52L194,52L190,48z"/>
                <path d="M188,50L192,54L192,82L188,86L184,82L184,54L188,50z"/>
                <path d="M228,50L232,54L232,82L228,86L224,82L224,54L228,50z"/>
                <path d="M190,88L194,84L222,84L226,88L222,92L194,92L190,88z"/>
            </g>
            <g class="separator">
                <circle r="4" cx="236" cy="28"/>
                <circle r="4" cx="227.5" cy="68"/>
            </g>
            <g class="digit" transform="skewX(-12)">
                <path d="M258,8L262,4L290,4L294,8L290,12L262,12L258,8z"/>
                <path d="M256,10L260,14L260,42L256,46L252,42L252,14L256,10z"/>
                <path d="M296,10L300,14L300,42L296,46L292,42L292,14L296,10z"/>
                <path d="M258,48L262,44L290,44L294,48L290,52L262,52L258,48z"/>
                <path d="M256,50L260,54L260,82L256,86L252,82L252,54L256,50z"/>
                <path d="M296,50L300,54L300,82L296,86L292,82L292,54L296,50z"/>
                <path d="M258,88L262,84L290,84L294,88L290,92L262,92L258,88z"/>
            </g>
            <g class="digit" transform="skewX(-12)">
                <path d="M314,8L318,4L346,4L350,8L346,12L318,12L314,8z"/>
                <path d="M312,10L316,14L316,42L312,46L308,42L308,14L312,10z"/>
                <path d="M352,10L356,14L356,42L352,46L348,42L348,14L352,10z"/>
                <path d="M314,48L318,44L346,44L350,48L346,52L318,52L314,48z"/>
                <path d="M312,50L316,54L316,82L312,86L308,82L308,54L312,50z"/>
                <path d="M352,50L356,54L356,82L352,86L348,82L348,54L352,50z"/>
                <path d="M314,88L318,84L346,84L350,88L346,92L318,92L314,88z"/>
            </g>
          </g>
        </svg>
      </body>
</html>
```

It took me a while to draw out the SVG already, however I just do not know how to implement the functions for the timer, current time and color change. I set the colors to a green color for now so that it is easy to see.
Here's [a link](http://obsidian.sru.edu/users/btw1004/CPSC337/Project/clock.html) so that you can view what I have so far

Answer (score 0):

Move your script inside the body, just above the `</body>`. And remove the onload from `<body>`.

Comment: What should I do next? I'm not quite sure, I'm still learning how to do a lot of this so I apologize if it seems relatively simple

Comment: Create a repository on GitHub, you might get some help.
Don't forget to put the link here.